# Is there a way to call an initialization function only when specific class template (specialization) is instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initialization, class-template

I'm designing a wrapper over various computational functionality. Some of the underlying backends require some init functions to be called before any other API calls are made. I could use some static variable that is initialized before main, and wrap it in some function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2330158/256138) so that I can catch any errors produced during initialization.

I wonder if there is a better way to handle this. Note that there will never be an instance of the class template, as everything is either a typedef or static member.

Comment: The title is totally wrong, it doesn't describe the question.

Comment: Why not delegate from the static members to a singleton instance - which will be initialized on the first use (and which can handle errors properly?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the problem of *initializing the API* only for some specializations, and of initializing it only once, I'd do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    // class who will be statically instantiated
    struct CtorClass
    {
        CtorClass()
        {
            std::cout << "Init\n";
        }
    };

    static CtorClass static_ctor;

    static void compute1(){}
    static void compute2(){}

};

// definition for template static member cons
template <typename T>
typename Wrapper<T>::CtorClass Wrapper<T>::static_ctor;

struct NeedInit{};

// you will have to use static_ctor in every funcition of the
template <>
void Wrapper<NeedInit>::compute1()
{
    static_ctor;
}

template <>
void Wrapper<NeedInit>::compute2()
{
    static_ctor;
}

int main()
{
    Wrapper<int>::compute1();
    Wrapper<int>::compute2();
    Wrapper<NeedInit>::compute1();
    Wrapper<NeedInit>::compute2();
}
```

Sadly, this way you have to use `static_ctor` in every function specialization that belongs to a `Wrapper<NeedInit>` class. But you wouldn't need to check for the initialization to have already been called.

Then, you could catch errors like you said.

Comment: Right, that's one of the ways I half-thought up. This does incur a runtime penalty, albeit a lot smaller penalty than having the user forced to call an init function. How does `std::cout` handle this? I thought it had some sort of mechanism of initializing stdio when it was used.

Comment: @rubenvb Mmm, don't know how cout handle io initialization. Maybe it's performed whenever <iostream> is included, even if cout is not used?