# Where am I supposed to catch the C++ exception thrown in the constructor?

Tags: c++, exception

**Header file:**

```
#ifndef MUTEXCLASS
#define MUTEXCLASS

#include <pthread.h>

class MutexClass
{
private:
    pthread_mutex_t & _mutexVariable;
public:
    MutexClass (pthread_mutex_t &);
    ~MutexClass ();
};

#endif // MUTEXCLASS
```

**Source file:**

```
#include "mutexClass.h"
#include <stdexcept>

MutexClass::MutexClass (pthread_mutex_t & arg) : _mutexVariable (arg)
{
    _mutexVariable  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    int returnValue = pthread_mutex_lock (&_mutexVariable);
    if (returnValue > 0)
    {
        throw std::logic_error ("Mutex couldn't be locked!");
    }
}

MutexClass::~MutexClass()
{
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&_mutexVariable);
}
```

**Where am I supposed to catch the exception thrown in the constructor?**

Comment: If the mutex can't be locked it's not a logic error, it's a runtime error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An exception thrown in a constructor can be handled

- by the code explicitly creating the object (`try { MutexClass m; ... } catch(const std::logic_error& e) { ... }`)
- by code creating an object that contains as member a `MutexClass` instance (including as base sub-object... i.e. by code that creates an object derived from `MutexClass`)
- by code calling code doing the creation as exceptions will un-wind the stack until some code handles them

Note that for exceptions thrown in constructor of objects that are members of bigger objects (either for an `has-a` or a `is-a` relationship) there is a tricky part. The destructor of the bigger object will **not** be called if the costruction of a member throws an exception... only the already constructed members will be destroyed before propagating the exception. For example a class like:

```
struct Foo {
    MyData * data;
    MutexClass m;
    MyData() : data(new int[1000]) { }
    ~MyData() { delete[] data; } // NOT called if m constructor throws
};
```

will leak memory if `MutexClass` constructor throws an exception.

Also before writing an exception handler however ask yourself if catching the exception is the right thing to do (i.e. if you know what to do when that condition occurs). Catching an exception and "hiding" it because you don't know what to do in that case is the worst possible choice.

In the specific case if you cannot lock a freshly created mutex can you expect the system to be still in good enough shape that keeping it running is a good idea?

Comment: You're making a mountain out of a molehill with your comments about "exceptions thrown in constructor of objects that are members of bigger objects".   If class `A` has members and/or bases, then the members and bases will be constructed before the (body of) `A`s constructor is called.  So, if construction of a member or base throws, it does not make sense for `A`s destructor to be called.        In your example, if `new int[1000]` throws, then the value of `data` is not even set, and there is no need to `delete [] data`.

Comment: @Peter: I said the problem is if `MutexClass` throws... because the destruction of a pointer will not release the memory. I'm not saying C++ is wrong on this point (the constructor didn't start, and calling the destructor with only some of the member initialized would be nonsense). I simply wanted to point out that exceptions during constructors also have this added complexity to think about.

Comment: I totally agree about the added complexity from throwing from constructors. Many think it just as fine as throwing from any other function. It is not. The only way to catch and deallocate would be to wrap the initializer list with a try/catch. The exception would still propagate further.

Answer (score 2):

As with any exception, anywhere up the stack where you can handle the exception. This is no way different from handling exceptions thrown in functions.

Comment: this is at most a comment!

Comment: @g24l, this definitely answers the question.

Comment: Really, how would you catch from static ? up which stack?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330117/how-to-catch-exception-thrown-while-initializing-a-static-member

Comment: @g24l, then you have no option to catch. And my main point stands: it's no way different from handling exceptions from functions, consider, e.g., `static int a = foo();`. And anyway, if _that's_ OP's question, then he should have clarified more. We can't guess any possible unusual situation unless it is specified in question

Comment: It is different, because static initialization that throws must be handled with Construct on first use idiom. Classes intended for static initialization (e.g. std::mutex) must have a non-throwing constructor. Otherwise you are putting bugs in everybody else's code.

Answer (score -2):

At the point of construction

```
try {
  MutexClass m(arg);
}catch( std::logic_error const & e)
{
}
```

or if you have a pointer

```
try {
  MutexClass * m = new MutexClass(arg);
}catch( std::logic_error const & e)
{
}
```

If you were able work with a pointer , passed to a function , surround the function.

E.g.

void funfun ( MutexClass * );

```
try {
  funfun(new MutexClass(arg));
}catch( std::logic_error const & e)
{
}
```

If you are going to construct the object in an initializer list:

```
class A
{
MutexClass mc;
A(pthread_mutex_t & m) try : mc(m)
{
} catch ( std::logic_error const & e )
{
// do something here to handle the failure 
// of mc(m) and the now the failure of A 
// must be handled in the construction point of A 
}
};
```

But now you have to handle the failure of the constructor of A as well.

Furthermore you should watch out for implicit conversions and copies, and you class is sadly copiable.

```
void funfun(MutexClass m );   

pthread_mutex & m;
try
{
  void funfun(m);
} catch( std::logic_error const & e )
{
}
```

[Read before throwing](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm) from a constructor.

Also don't forget that such constructors are not good as static members.
So this type of class may break your program

```
class maybreak 
{
private:

static MutexClass mc;

// ....

};
```

unless a [wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2332936/4345926) function method is defined to put the construction of the static after your program actually starts ([COFU](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use-members)).