# How to catch exception originating from constructor of statically allocated object?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, static, terminate

How can catch an exception being thrown from the constructor of a statically allocated object? Or at least how I can handle such an exception (like set_terminate or smth.) to perform some teardown logic before termination:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(){throw std::exception();}
};

static A a;

int main(){}
```

Comment: you can't. it's started right after you enter the main.

Comment: @OstrichGroomer Before, even.  It would, at best, terminate the program, I would think.

Comment: So you need the object to be declared that way? Can you change the program slightly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330117/how-to-catch-exception-thrown-while-initializing-a-static-member (some useful answers there).

Answer (score 0):

The general work around for having global variables is a function with a static member.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(){throw std::exception();}
};

A& getA()
{
    static A a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    try {
        getA();
    }
    catch(...) {
        // error
    }
}
```

Now You still effectively have a global variable. **BUT** the variable is initialized on first use. If you do this for all globals then the globals will not be initialized before main starts and you can out the try catch in main().